# Is there some way to measure time taken by MPI Isend/Irecv?

Tags: mpi, hpc

The title says it all. How can I measure the time taken by MPI non-blocking point to point communications?

Comment: The important point is to measure how much time is spent in `MPI_Wait()`. If the wait time is virtually none, who cares how much time was spent moving data since it was fully overlapped with useful computations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the time for the actual `Isend` call is close to zero. Put a timer before and after it and you'll see.

Secondly, if you're wondering about the time for the actual transfer, that is hard to measure because the clocks on different processes are not synchronized. (You can query whether they are, but it's unlikelly.)

Thirdly, the best you can do is time a ping-pong: you send a message from A to B, and then back from B to A. The time for a send is half of that.

If you're wondering about the difference between blocking and non-blocking, try a ping-pong both ways. You won't see much difference. However, non-blocking sends have the potential to be overlapped with computation. However^2, this is often hard to attain in practice. You may need some implementation-specific mechanism such as a "progress thread" for it. See the manual of your MPI.